# Torque PBS_Server

Tags: hpc, torque

does anyone know how to get the process id (pid) of a submitted job on a computing node. 
I need the pid to run some scripts for analysing the ressources of a job.

I am using Torque version 4.1.2.

Thanks!

Comment: qstat -f | grep session_id will show you the session id.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Torque server let you know this type on information.
But, you can write smalls scripts (prologue and epilogue) that will let you know useful informations about the job on compute node(s).

See Torque admin guide about Prologue and Epilogue.